# How to use input form values in google chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have created a form and trying to display submitted values in the google chart. I have tried to create wrapper for drawChart() and want to load drawChart() after submit button is clicked. But, drawChart() function gets called onload. What is the problem with my code?

HTML-

```
 <form method= "post" action = "#" id="formValue"> 
        <label><input type="number" value="1" id="ip1"/>inpu1</label>
        <label><input type="number" value="2" id="ip2"/> input2</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" onclick="initializer()"/>
    </form>
```

JS-

```
<script>
var ip1, ip2;
var str = "hello";
var str2 = "hello2";
function initializer(){
    ip1 = document.getElementById("ip1").value;
    ip2 = document.getElementById("ip2").value;
    drawChart();
}
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initializer);
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

function drawChart() {
    var x2= [
    [
        str,
        ip1
    ],
    [
        str2,
        ip2
    ]
];
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows(x2);

    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':500,
                   'height':600};


    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this...

`google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initializer);`

it runs `initializer` when...

`google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});`

is finished.

Comment: see [Load the Libraries](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs) for more info...

Comment: I removed `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initializer);`, but maps load for a flash of second and then blanks out. Thanks

Comment: sorry, _maps_? is that part of the code in the question? will you edit with the latest?

Comment: sorry. charts load for a flash of second and then screen is blank again. I only removed `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initializer);` from the code